# How and Where should I add the main method to run?

Tags: java, program-entry-point

So i feel as if the code is complete and ready to run, but I am having trouble with the basics and completely forgot where to put the main method and what to put in it. 
My class is called "Cell" and has a few methods and such in it, now i want to run it, sorry if i didnt give enough details, hopefully you all will understand. 
CODE:

```
public class Cell {
//We need an array for the cells and one for the rules.

  public int[] cells = new int[9];

  public int[] ruleset = {0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0};







  //Compute the next generation.

public void generate() 
{

//All cells start with state 0, except the center cell has state 1.

    for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
    {
      cells[i] = 0;
    }

    cells[cells.length/2] = 1;


    int[] nextgen = new int[cells.length];
    for (int i = 1; i < cells.length-1; i++)
    {
      int left   = cells[i-1];
      int me     = cells[i];
      int right  = cells[i+1];
      nextgen[i] = rules(left, me, right);
    }
    cells = nextgen;

}

//Look up a new state from the ruleset.

  public int rules (int a, int b, int c)

  {
      if      (a == 1 && b == 1 && c == 1) return ruleset[0];

        else if (a == 1 && b == 1 && c == 0) return ruleset[1];

        else if (a == 1 && b == 0 && c == 1) return ruleset[2];

        else if (a == 1 && b == 0 && c == 0) return ruleset[3];

        else if (a == 0 && b == 1 && c == 1) return ruleset[4];

        else if (a == 0 && b == 1 && c == 0) return ruleset[5];

        else if (a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 1) return ruleset[6];

        else if (a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0) return ruleset[7];


        return 0;
  }{


}
}
```

Comment: Read this tutorial : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/

Comment: Any class with a `public static void main(String[] args)` will do. You can put the main method into the `Cell` class itself or write a dedicated class for that.

Comment: I think `public int rules (int a, int b, int c)` could be optimized the assignment of a, b and c to the ruleset indices is the complementary binary nummber (a,b,c). E. g. (1,1,0) -> (0,0,1) = 0*4 +0*2 + 1*1 = 1, (0,0,0) -> (1,1,1) = 1*4 + 1*2 + 1*1 = 7.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Cell cell = new Cell();
cell.generate();
}
```

add this in your Cell class itself

Comment: It would be wise to follow conventions and use `String[] args` instead.

Comment: The thing is, when i run that main method code nothing happens. is it because Generate() is a void and cant return anything?

Comment: `generate()` internally updates `int[] cells`. So, yes the method is void and returns nothing. But it has side effects. You should try `System.out.println(cell.cells)` before and after the call to `generate()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the **main method** anywhere inside the **class declaration**:

```
//this is your class declaration for class Cell!
public class Cell {

  //We need an array for the cells and one for the rules.
  public int[] cells = new int[9];
  public int[] ruleset = {0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0};


  //You can write main method here!


  //Compute the next generation.
  public void generate() 
  {
    //code
  }


  //Or you can write main method here!


  //Look up a new state from the ruleset.
  public int rules (int a, int b, int c)
  {
    //code
  }


  //Or, heck, you can write main method here:
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    //sample code:
    Cell cell = new Cell();
    cell.generate();

    //loop through updated array list.
    for(int i = 0; i<cell.cells.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("cells[" + i + "]:  " + cell.cells[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("main method complete!");

  }


}
```

You can also create a whole other class and create a main method in there to use this Cell class you wrote.

Note:  You have a bracket error near the end of your code which I fixed here.

Comment: The thing is, when i run that main method code nothing happens. is it because Generate() is a void and cant return anything?

Comment: Yes, but I'm assuming you want to print the cells[] array?

Comment: Updated the code inside the main method.  I think that's what you  need.

Comment: No problem!  I recommend creating a method to print out the entire cells array, so it makes your main method look cleaner.